# Uninstall every program that I've installed

Tags: apt, uninstall

I'm triying to make a bash file to uninstall every program that I've installed, but I don't know how to do it, is there any specific command to list every program that I've installed manually or using apt-get and then to remove them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packages you have installed with a package manager (`dpkg`, `apt-get`, `synaptic`) are logged in `/var/log/apt/`, but software you installed manually (`sudo make install`,etc) has to be tracked manually, too.

Answer (score 0):

There should be as if you go to the software centre you can see all the apps that are installed on your system. The only thing that I can think about if you were going to do a batch file would be that you would have to make it smart enough to determine which apps came with the system itself. Say a line like anything installed after the original install date.

Whist looking I did come across this line that produces a text file with all apps. I have not had chance to try it out yet so cannot say of it works. Thought it may be of help to you:

```
man dpkg
# `sudo` is not needed here
dpkg --get-selections > installed-applications.txt
```

Comment: I'm using a VPS so I only have SSH access

Comment: I've got this http://pastebin.com/mNXWYq2z